# Password Confirmation with has_secure_password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activemodel

I'm using the line `has_secure_password` in my `User` model. It looks like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    before_create :create_remember_token
  validates :name, presence: true, length: {minimum: 3, maximum: 22},
                            uniqueness: true
  #validates :password, presence: true, length: {minimum: 6, maximum: 22}
    VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
    validates :email, :allow_blank => true, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX }
  has_secure_password
  validates :password, length: {minimum: 6}
```

In my `User`s new view, I have this:

```
<h1>Sign up</h1>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>

      <%= f.label :name, 'Username' %>
      <%= f.text_field :name %>

      <%= f.label :email, 'Email (Optional)' %>
      <%= f.text_field :email %>

      <%= f.label :password %>
      <%= f.password_field :password %>

      <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirmation" %>
      <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>

      <%= f.submit "Create my account", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

From what I read, the `has_secure_password` bit was supposed to "automagically" create and validate the password confirmation stuff. However, it doesn't throw anything when I create a user with a non matching `password` and `password_confirmation`.

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

```
EDIT: forgot this       params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password,
       line right here----->                       :password_confirmation)
```

Comment: Can you post code of `users_controller.rb`? Especially `user_params` part.

Comment: @ekremkrc Oh my. I just found the problem. My user_param bit was missing :password_confirmation. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question I'm not sure if user is created without match password and it's confirmation or if only error messages aren't shown. So I'll try to answer both of these issues.

The form don't throw information about errors because you have no code to view that. Add this piece of code at the begining of your form to show flash errors in your form.

```
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
  <% if @user.errors.any? %>
    <div class="error_messages">
      <h2>Form is invalid</h2>
      <ul>
        <% for message in @user.errors.full_messages %>
          <li><%= message %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>
....
```

Other thing might be wrong is here:

```
    has_secure_password
    validates :password, length: {minimum: 6}
```

You validate minimum length of password, but not it's presence. Try to change second line with: 
        validates :password, presence: true, length: {minimum: 6}

If not work, make sure that you access password and password_confirmation fields in your model ( rails 3) or controller (rails 4):

If you use rails 3, the code should be added in your model to access all parameters you wan't to allow in forms:

```
app/models/user.rb
attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation
```

And if you use rails 4, it should be like this:

```
app/controllers/users_controller.rb
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
end
```

Hope it will help.